# Linux aarch64 security update provision, Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, updates, raspberry-pi

Do any of the major Linux distributions (Fedora, Debian, Arch, Ubuntu, etc.) provide timely security updates for the `aarch64` architecture for kernel and other standard system components present in a default 'desktop' install (I'll define that as the 'most standard install' that will run a web browser)?  Have any of the relevant security teams indicated any (informal) commitment to ongoing and timely updates?

I ask in the context of SBC (single board computers), in particular Raspberry Pi 3.

As an example of the possible shortcomings I have in mind, [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=414686) indicates that security updates in Raspbian back in 2013 were sometimes unavailable (and in fact I believe I read elsewhere from a Raspbian maintainer that their kernel updates in particular were not always as timely as for other system components, because of the modifications made by the Raspbian team).

Comment: this is more about updates than it is about security - you might get better engagement on the Pi StackExchange: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks.  However, I don't think the Raspberry Pi community is focused on security very much.  I think it is also focused mostly on Raspbian.